# admin and frontend folder separation laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new in Laravel 4 and I want to know the standard structure of folder. I have a problem with separation of folder with admin panle and front end file and folder in laravel 4. Please help me that how can we made the standard folder structure in laravel 4.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel comes with a predefined folder structure that is usually fine for the majority of web applications (especially for new-comers). The structure is this:

```
/app
    /commands
    /config
    /controllers
    /database
    /lang
    /models
    /start
    /storage
    /tests
    /views
/bootstrap
/public
```

You'll spend most of your time in `app/controllers`, `app/models`, `app/views` and `public`.

By default all the major things are automatically loaded for you. So for separation, you'd want a folder for both `Frontend` and `Backend` in the following directories.

```
/app
    /commands
    /config
    /controllers
        /Backend
        /Frontend
    /database
    /lang
    /models
        /Backend
        /Frontend
    /start
    /storage
    /tests
    /views
        /backend
        /frontend
```

You'll then, for example, use namespaces in your controllers.

```
<?php namespace Backend;

use Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

}
```

You might find that your models are the same for both front and backend. If that's the case you don't need to duplicate the code.

But when it comes down to it. The way you structure your project is mainly left it your hands. Laravel does ship with this default folder structure and it's great as a start, but many will find growing pains when they start to develop a more complex and evolving application. Once you've hit that point you should be at a level where you know what kind of structure you want and need.

Comment: Where will be the BaseController.php file in controller?

Comment: If you use controller layouts (the only benefit of that base controller) then you might like to have a base controller for both front and backends. That way you can set a different $layout property for both.

Comment: If i will use in both folder BaseController.php and same class then on update composer it will give the error.

Comment: They should be namespaced according to their respective folders (Backend and Frontend). Look, comments on SO aren't really designed for discussing a problem and how to solve it. I suggest you jump into #laravel IRC on Freenode and ask for some help.

Comment: I have also post in laravel forum but not getting any response. It is totally worst documentation.

Comment: You can see http://laravel.io/forum/04-16-2014-folder-separation-for-admin-and-front-end?page=1#reply-5219